# "Business user" and "non-business user"?

Tags: phrase-requests, software

I need to categorize users of a software system based on whether they use the software for work purposes or in their personal life. What should I call those categories? Here are some alternatives: *business user*, *at-work user*, *commercial user*, and respectively: *consumer user*, *private user*, *personal user*.

Comment: What's the nature of the software?  Utility, reference, education, game, etc.

Comment: You typically have categories like Personal/Home, Business, etc.

Comment: I'm sorry and although some months I've met such choices daily, I suggest they matter hardly at all.

Do you really care exactly *how* anyone uses the software?

Then are you not left with not *how* but *how much*?

Most businesses have more than one user… but that’s also true of many home users, particularly in licencing as used by Microsoft which, after all, defines the market.

If you look closely at how and why you need to categorise what, will it not make itself either clear or irrelevant?

Don’t Trevor D’s and AleksandrH’s comments make more obvious?

Comment: The reason for having user categories is the General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR). So it's not about how you use the software, only the terms and legal stuff. As for the nature of the software I would say it's a utility kind of software package.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following category names for the software. Here's a [link to the Office 365 subscription page](https://products.office.com/en-us/compare-all-microsoft-office-products?tab=1) as an example. You can browse other software to get a feel for what the industry uses, but these are pretty common/standard.

- Home/Personal (ordinary users)
- Business (small-to-medium-sized businesses)
- Enterprise (large corporations)